# Move file in Gogle colab from folder to hdfs

Tags: hadoop, google-colaboratory

I want to move my file from its path "/content/lastfm-dataset-1K/userid-timestamp-artid-artname-traid-traname.tsv" to the /user/root/ folder of hdfs and I don't know how

[image: the file is already uploaded]

and i need to move it here:

[image: destination directory]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hdfs dfs -put` command to upload files to hdfs